# How can I support file upload in jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, jqgrid

My web app is based on ASP.net MVC3 and uses jqGrid. I am stuck with supporting a required file upload functionality from jqGrid.

The web app useflow allows the user to select a file on their system and upload it to a database record from the jqGrid Add/Edit form. The jqGrid colModel for file upload has edit type set as `edittype:'file'`. In the Add/Edit form, I am able to view the "browse..." button to select an image. The jqGrid documentation suggests using the Ajax File upload plugin for file upload. I found two plugins with this name and tried both.

1. Ajax file upload plugin from [PHPLetter](http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo): This plugin works with jqGrid but only when using older versions of jQuery. The functionality is broken since jQuery 1.5 due to the usage of the HandleError undocumented API in the file upload plugin.
2. Ajax file upload plugin from [Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload). I have been able to successfully use this plugin from outside of jqGrid. The script I use for file upload (outside my grid) is as follows:

   ```
   var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
          element: fileUploader,
          action: @Url.Action("UploadProductImage"), 
          allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'], )};
   ```

However, I am yet to figure out a means to integrate this plugin in the jqgrid Add/Edit form. How do I initialize my upload script and invoke it??

I cannot use a Flash/HTML5 based file upload solution (e.g. Uploadify) since my app needs to work with IE 7 and 8. I appreciate any tips/suggestions.

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: possible duplicate of [jqgrid - upload a file in add/edit dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550304/jqgrid-upload-a-file-in-add-edit-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to write my own very short HandleError function and still use the Ajax File Upload plugin as described in [jqgrid - upload a file in add/edit dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550304/jqgrid-upload-a-file-in-add-edit-dialog). So I use that solution but I add the following function:

```
jQuery.extend({
    handleError: function( s, xhr, status, e ) {
        // If a local callback was specified, fire it
        if ( s.error )
            s.error( xhr, status, e );
        // If we have some XML response text (e.g. from an AJAX call) then log it in the console
        else if(xhr.responseText)
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }    
});
```

I found the function here: http://www.johnmain.co.uk/blog/2012/06/14/jquery-handleerror-is-not-a-function-issues/

Note one more thing: I had to change the line

```
dataType: 'json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'JSON',
```

in order to get the code from [jqgrid - upload a file in add/edit dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550304/jqgrid-upload-a-file-in-add-edit-dialog) working in Firefox (in other browsers this should not be an issue).

Comment: This is great - but where do i put the $.extend({...}) function?

Comment: I put it right at the top of my javascript, just under the text/javascript tag before calling any other JQuery functionality. It is a standalone javascript function; doesn't have to be embedded within some other function.