# How to make Ajax File Upload with Jqgrid work synchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using the AjaxFileUpload plugin from http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/.

I am trying to do a file upload from a form editing box in Jqgrid. Since I am doing the file upload in an edit form (Jqgrid form editing) that also updates other fields, I am linking the call to the **AjaxFileUpload** function to the **beforeSubmit** event on the Jqgrid. This enables me to return the response from AjaxFileUpload to Jqgrid before other form data is submitted. So in case there is an error with the file upload, I can return an error to Jqgrid and it won't submit the form. (The form will only be submitted if file upload is successful.)

However, in order for the above to work I need AjaxFileUpload to work synchronously and not asynchronously as is the default. I have set async:false but it still seems to be working asynchronously. I know this because if in Firebug I add a breakpoint to the success function and the error function (so that execution is paused for a few seconds for file upload to complete) then everything works 100% as expected. However, the moment I remove the breakpoints so that execution happens in real-time the response returned by the success or error functions is still undefined.

How can I make AjaxFileUpload behave synchronously? Extract of my code below:

```
function ajaxFileUpload(formid)
{
    var uploadresponse = [false, "by default"];

    $.ajaxFileUpload(
        {
            url:'EditData.aspx?MyIdentifier=' + $("#MyIdentifier").val(),
            secureuri:false,
            fileElementId:'filename',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {id: formid},
            async:false,                
            success: function (dataIn, status)
            {
                var errorResponse = $.parseJSON(dataIn);
                if((errorResponse != null)&&(typeof(errorResponse.error) != 'undefined'))
                {
                    if(errorResponse.error != '')
                    {
                        uploadresponse = [false, errorResponse.explanation];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    uploadresponse = [true, "Successfully uploaded file"];
                }
            },
            error: function (datain, status, e)
            {
                uploadresponse = [false, e];
            }
        }
    );
    return uploadresponse;
}
```

(In the code above, if I don't set breakpoints then the response in uploadresponse is always [false, "by default"] but if I set breakpoints then uploadresponse is set correctly as per the success and error functions.)

Comment: I'll look into your question later(I'm at work). You can check this link by then. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7550304/jqgrid-upload-a-file-in-add-edit-dialog

Comment: That is the link where I've already got most of my information to write the function. That link, however, doesn't use synchronous upload (it uses default asynchronous). In their case they are linking it to jqgrid through the use of the afterSubmit event (not beforeSubmit like me) which means the file upload happens **after** submitting the form and not before. This suggests that they didn't need validation on upload response before submitting the rest of the form which means they didn't really have a need for making upload synchronous as I do.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? I've looked at some of your other questions and you seem to know a lot about Jquery...

Comment: i looked around and your code seems fine to me so then i looked into plugin and i couldn't find something which is related to this async property. perhaps this plugin doesn't support async. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/can-jquery-form-plugin-be-synchronous   i found this article on Jquery forums.